# moving files and folders to a subfolder

Tags: linux, bash, busybox

I would like to move all files and folder from one directory to one of its subfolders. How do I do that?

I am using BusyBox and linux.

ex:

move all files and folder in `/my/path/` to `/my/path/subfolder/.`

Copy, and then delete solutions are not affordable.

Thanks.

Comment: A GUI file manager might be a good option, shouldn't have any surprises

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more digging and experimentation. I found the answer:
`-prune` is used to avoid recusing into sub-directories. `! -name` is used to exclude the target sub-directory, and then `exec` executes the move operation. The `{}` is replaced with file/directory names from the `find` command.

```
find /my/path/* -prune ! -name subfolder -exec mv {} /my/path/subfolder/. +
```

Comment: What `find` implementation can do this? Normally `… -exec mv {} /my/path/subfolder/. +` fails because you cannot separate `{}` and `+`, they must be at the very end: `{} +`; this is not the case with `\;`.

Comment: This may be unnecessarily complex.

Comment: I am using busyBox

Answer (score 11):

```
mv * subfolder
```

Of course, it will fail moving the "subfolder" directory into itself, but everything else will move

Comment: Is this in mv's specification? or is this hoping to be lucky? it may stop at first failure and I will end up with some of files and folder being moves but not all.

Comment: @hebbo it will not stop at first failure

Comment: * excludes hidden files (or so testing shows me, though there's probably a setting for it somewhere)

Comment: Files with name starting with a dot (like _.git_) are excluded to. To hotfix this run `mv .* subfolder` (mv dot-start subfolder)

Comment: didnt work for me

Answer (score 2):

Solutions that use `*` (expanded by shell) won't work with too many objects in `/my/path/`. In such case you'll get:

> ```
> argument list too long
> ```

This approach doesn't use `*`:

```
cd /my/path/ &&
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 ! -name subfolder -exec mv -t subfolder/ {} +
```

Unfortunately `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` options of `find` are not POSIX-compliant; neither `-t` option of `mv` is, I think.

This variant should satisfy POSIX:

```
cd /my/path/ &&
find . ! -name . -prune ! -name subfolder -exec mv {} subfolder/ \;
```

(I adapted [this Unix & Linux SE answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/373001/108618)). Sadly it calls `mv` for every object found, thus it's slow.

---

Fast alternative approach, if only you can create directories anew (initially neither `/my/path/subfolder/` nor `/my/subfolder/` should exist):

- rename `path/` to `subfolder/`,
- recreate `path/`,
- move `subfolder/` into `path/`.

Note on inode-based filesystem this should be equally fast, no matter how many objects there are in `path/`. The code:

```
cd /my/ &&
test ! -e subfolder/ && mv path/ subfolder/ &&
mkdir path/ &&
mv subfolder/ path/
```

In this case I used `&&` a lot to emphasize the procedure should abort if any of its steps fails. However this approach is inconvenient if you need `path/` or `subfolder/` to have non-default permissions, ownership etc.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is:

```
mv !(subfolder) subfolder
```

'!' means NOT, similar to programming languages, where mv will move all files and folders to the required subfolder with the exception of the subfolder.

Additional things like moving hidden folders and dot folders are described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/91740/how-to-move-all-files-in-current-folder-to-subfolder

Comment: This did not work with the version of find I am using.

Comment: This has nothing with `find` to do. It uses the `mv` command but more crucially the shell's wildcard feature. You have to enable `shopt -s extglob` in many versions on Bash to get access to this "extended globbing" wildcard syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Although i'm a bit late, I was in the same situation and came with a different solution that won't trigger anything to stdout, stderr or provide non-null exit code.

In case it can help someone:

```
items=(*)
mkdir subfolder
mv ${items[*]} subfolder
```

In case you have filenames containing spaces, you will have to add `IFS=''` at the first line to properly escape them (which was my case).

Comment: This is really useful. However, `items=(*)` ignores dot-files like .gitignore

Comment: (Cannot edit comment after 5 minutes)

However, `(* .[!.]*)` seems to work fine for me:
`IFS='';items=(* .[!.]*);mkdir subfolder;mv ${items[*]} subfolder`

Comment: This will fail on file names with spaces or newlines etc in their names. You want `mv "${items[@]}" subfolder`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the `mv` command.  You can try searching for all files and folders in a directory and exclude a sub-directory then copy all found to that sub-directory using `find` with the `mv` command.

See a similar stack-overflow question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612157/how-to-use-mv-command-to-move-files-except-those-in-a-specific-directory